# Update when value changed jquery/javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So when I initally use .append to append a string variable in javascript "myvar" to a div tag. If later on the "myvar" is set to some other string.. I want the div tag with th appended myvar (or anywhere that uses the myvar variable) to be updated to reflect the new value as well. How to accomplish this in jquery/javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you change the value of myvar you'll need to update the HTML as well. You could wrap that in something nice like:
`function setMyVar(val) {
    myVar = val;
    $('#myVar').html(val);
}`

You would need to adjust your initial append a little to accomodate this:

`$('div').append('<div id="myVar">' + myVar + '</div>');`

Answer (score 0):

There is now real time automatic data binding of variable -> text of dom element in HTML and jQuery by the nature of JS - there is no event like "variable changed" or so.

You can emulate live data binding for example like this:
http://www.grantshepert.com/post.cfm/jquery-and-data-binding-to-form-fields
But this will also require function invocation when data changes.